# Rule-based labeling using Atlas - QGIS.3.6.2

Tags: atlas, rule-based

I'm working with two shapes, both of them have a common field called "ID". I need the atlas to filter, only the id that I need to use, in the two layers.

The point layer has an entry point and an exit point for the same id.

Try this option but it did not work, in the non-coverage layer,

"ID" = attribute (@atlas_feature, 'ID') (mentioned by Alexandre Neto) 
[Rule-based labeling using Atlas - QGIS.2.14.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194323/rule-based-labeling-using-atlas-qgis-2-14-1)
[image]

I HAVE TRIED THESE FORMS BUT I DO NOT HAVE RESULTS.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your sentence on QGIS 3.4.7 and it worked.

> "ID" = attribute (@atlas_feature, 'ID')

You are mentioning the Atlas, so you need a Layout with a selected Atlas. Hit the button "Preview Atlas". Only that way this rule will work.
[image]

Another way to do this, is to set the **Page name** as **"ID"** at the Layout, and use this rule

> "ID" = @atlas_pagename

In this case, the rule-based filter will continuos to be applied, even if you turn off the Preview Atlas.
[image]